# PNG Transparency with PHP

Tags: php, png, transparency

Hey having some trouble trying to maintain transparency on a png when i create a thumbnail from it, anyone any experience with this? any help would be great, here's what i am currently doing:

```
$fileName= "../js/ajaxupload/tees/".$fileName;

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($fileName);

$newwidth = 257;
$newheight = 197;

$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
imagealphablending($thumb, true);
$source = imagecreatefrompng($fileName);
imagealphablending($source, true);

imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

imagesavealpha($thumb, true);
imagepng($thumb,$newFilename);
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I have had success doing it like this in the past:

```
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
imagealphablending($thumb, false);
imagesavealpha($thumb, true);  

$source = imagecreatefrompng($fileName);
imagealphablending($source, true);

imagecopyresampled($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

imagepng($thumb,$newFilename);
```

I found the output image quality much better using `imagecopyresampled()` than `imagecopyresized()`

Comment: that cracked it! much obliged!

Comment: Using imagecopyresampled is what finally worked for me, so not only did it improve the quality, but imagecopyresized wouldn't respect the transparency anyways.

Comment: That exact code did not work for me, but changing imagealphablending($thumb, false); to imagealphablending($thumb, true); on line 2 fixed it.

Answer (score 14):

Forget the color transparency index, it never works in all rendering products. Instead use an alpha layer mask:

```
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($size, $size);

imagealphablending($image, false);
imagesavealpha($image, true);

$trans_layer_overlay = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 220, 220, 220, 127);
imagefill($image, 0, 0, $trans_layer_overlay);
```

Comment: Awesome! Wasted more than an hour to figure this out and your solution is the only one worked!

Comment: Perfect than ever!. You are great man @user629089.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you explain why you used `220, 220, 220`?

Answer (score 3):

Those functions access the underlying gdlib library, which is a fine toy, but not something that makes for nice results. If you have the option, use [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) instead. The downside is that there are currently no good php-bindings, so you need to access it over the shell, which you're usually not allowed on shared hosts.

Answer (score 1):

See [dycey's answer to "How do I resize..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279236/how-do-i-resize-pngs-with-transparency-in-php#279310). Essentially, you need to fill the entire background with transparency before you do any other operations.

Comment: You don't need to fill the entire background with transparency, but GD isn't great at dealing with opacity unless it's 100% (completely opaque) or 0% (completely transparent)

Answer (score 1):

[imagecopyresized](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php) does not support transparency properly.

[imagecopymerge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php) does, but it doesn't resize.

The solution?  You'd probably end up resizing the thing manually.

Comment: `imagecopyresampled` is a better solution, particularly for user-submitted images which can't be resized manually prior to upload; I don't feel that this answer is very helpful.