# Upload image without losing quality

Tags: php

I use this class to upload and resize images. The problem is that images have bad quality! I need to upload images without losing quality at all!

```
class SimpleImage {

   var $image;
   var $image_type;

   function load($filename) {
      $image_info = getimagesize($filename);
      $this->image_type = $image_info[2];
      if( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
      } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
         $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
      } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
         $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
      }       
   }

   function save($filename, $image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $compression=75, $permissions=null) {
      if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         imagejpeg($this->image,$filename,$compression);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
         imagegif($this->image,$filename);         
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
         imagepng($this->image,$filename);
      }   
      if( $permissions != null) {
         chmod($filename,$permissions);
      }
   }
   function output($image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
      if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         imagejpeg($this->image);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
         imagegif($this->image);         
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
         imagepng($this->image);
      }   
   }

   function getWidth() {
      return imagesx($this->image);
   }

   function getHeight() {
      return imagesy($this->image);
   }

   function resizeToHeight($height) {
      $ratio = $height / $this->getHeight();
      $width = $this->getWidth() * $ratio;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }

   function resizeToWidth($width) {
      $ratio = $width / $this->getWidth();
      $height = $this->getheight() * $ratio;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }

   function scale($scale) {
      $width = $this->getWidth() * $scale/100;
      $height = $this->getheight() * $scale/100; 
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }

   function resize($width,$height) {
      $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
      imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
      $this->image = $new_image;   
   }      
}
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: The quality problem has been fixed but there is one more problem. When I upload transparent png images, the transparent parts got black. How can be this fixed?

Comment: see e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313070/png-transparency-with-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a `75` as a default for the `$compression` parameter. You pass that as the quality parameter for [imagejpeg](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php). This is what probably generates the quality loss.

Answer (score 7):

one thing you can do is when you call to function save,

change quality parameter from 75 to 100 , when you call [imagejpeg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php)

quality is optional, and ranges from 0 (worst quality, smaller file) to 100 (best quality, biggest file). The default is the default IJG quality value (about 75).

Comment: Watch out with `imagepng` because it's numbers go from `9 - 0` (yes, backwards).

Comment: I think for perfect image 90, but regular usage 85 acceptable value.

Answer (score 0):

You save function defaults the quality value to 75. So either change it when you call it to 100 or change the default to 100. 100 is the best quality.