# Images getting weird (losing all quality) after PHP upload

Tags: php, image-processing, file-upload, image-uploading

#### Real image:

[image: Real image]

#### Image after PHP upload:

[image: Image after PHP upload]

What's the explanation for that?

Those things have started to happen suddenly. I don't remember doing anything to my code. It is the same since the beginning. I'm afraid those things are happening because of the PHP version (the code is **very old**, kinda 2002).

---

**P.s:** The code is also big, so I want to know what part of the code should I post.

Comment: is it up on github somewhere? maybe the part that relates to the upload would help. maybe check both original images on http://regex.info/exif.cgi and discover the difference

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034285/upload-image-without-losing-quality

Comment: Gist: https://gist.github.com/torquatto/8151d6ef5e7b83dad4dc

Comment: Looks like some color reduction happened. The uploaded image has less than 128 colors while the original one is a true color one

Comment: Maravilha, I'd say this is somehow related to the `resizeUploadedFiles` class. are you able to disable resizing? which component are you using? GD, GD2 of NetPBM?

Comment: GD, but I haven't tried the other ones yet. Should I?

Comment: Filype,  I guess it worked with GD2. ;D Thank you for noticing about components! But... why GD wasnt working? It worked one day!

Comment: is this your first png upload? what happens if you upload a jpg?

Comment: The same, actually. Happens to any pic.

Comment: Do some work tracking down the bug yourself, find the portion that might actually be causing the error, and if you're still having problems, upload a specific question about the issue.  At this point, you're asking people to debug your code for you, and you haven't even provided it.

Comment: I'm trying and you can be sure I've tried some workarounds yet. Didn't work. I didn't find the issue. 
But I've got some ideas now, after reading the things the people has posted for helping. I didn't mean to ask anyone to debug for me, I was just looking for some ideas.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the resizing should tell you if the resizing is causing the issue.

Also note that you have a variable `quality` in `resizeUploadedFiles` make sure this is set to 100.

I'd strongly encourage the use of a framework for this such as: [PHP file upload](https://github.com/aivis/PHP-file-upload-class)