# Preserve PNG transparency while resizing with out the black background

Tags: php, png, transparency, image-manipulation, gd

I have a small class which handles image manipulation.

I use following to resize a image

```
$this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
....
$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
...
$this->image = $new_image; 
imagepng($this->image,$filename)) { return true; }
```

But the resized image is not preserving transparency, instead black is comming, how can i preserve the transparency.

### Update

After, using @Manuel's code, black portion has decreased, but still black background are still present. The source image and the resulting image are

Source & Sub corresponding

[main http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/820a0.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/820a0.png) [sub http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/30526.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/30526.png)

Comment: you should check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313070/png-transparency-with-php)

Answer (score 3):

The newest comment, posted on the 8th of May, on the manual page for [`imagecopyresampled`](http://php.net/imagecopyresampled), tells you how to do this.

```
imagecolortransparent($new_image, imagecolorallocatealpha($new_image, 0, 0, 0, 127));
imagealphablending($new_image, false);
imagesavealpha($new_image, true);
```

Put that right after creating `$new_image`.

Comment: what doesw that $new contain. will this work for all types, or just pngs

Answer (score 1):

add this before the `imagecopyresampled(...)`

```
// preserve transparency
imagecolortransparent($new_image , imagecolorallocatealpha($new_image , 0, 0, 0, 127));
imagealphablending($new_image , false);
imagesavealpha($new_image , true);
```

Comment: but i am still getting black bgs, but is less amount that before

Comment: Ok, you can check the update, thats the result after using your code.