# Outputting an image not working properly

Tags: php, image

I'm trying to output an image with `PHP`, but when I do it, it won't look as the original image. The original image has transparent background, and the outputted image has some weird background which "kills" the image.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$image = imagecreatefrompng('./logo2.png');
$imagesize = getimagesize('./logo2.png');
header('Content-type: ' . $imagesize['mime']);
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

If you need anything else in order to determine the issue, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Add alpha blending:

```
<?php
$image = imagecreatefrompng('./logo2.png');
$imagesize = getimagesize('./logo2.png');
header('Content-type: ' . $imagesize['mime']);

imagealphablending($image, true);
imagesavealpha( $image, true );

imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

This was answered for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313070/png-transparency-with-php):