# PNG Transparency Resize with SimpleImage.php Class

Tags: php, class, resize, png, transparency

I'm using a modified version of the SimpleImage.php class: http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/articles/php-image-resizing.php

The edits I found on phpfreaks (http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=301811.0), but when I use, the png gets resized but the transparency is black.

I make the call like:

```
 $max_width = 200; // set a max width
 $max_height = 150; // set a max height
 if($imgW > $imgH){ // width is greater
      // resize to width up to max
      if($imgW > $max_width) $image->resizeToWidth($max_width);
 }
 else { // height is greater
      // resize to height up to max
      if($imgH > $max_height) $image->resizeToHeight($max_height);
 }

 $image->save($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/path/" . $new_filename);
```

I'm not sure what's missing. Any help is appreciated...

```
class SimpleImage {
     var $image;
     var $image_type;

     function load($filename) {
        $image_info = getimagesize($filename);
        $this->image_type = $image_info[2];
        if( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
            $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
        } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
            $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
        } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
            $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
        }
    }
    function save($filename, $image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $compression=75, $permissions=null) {
        if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
            imagejpeg($this->image,$filename,$compression);
        } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
            imagegif($this->image,$filename);
        } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
            imagepng($this->image,$filename);
        }
        if( $permissions != null) {
            chmod($filename,$permissions);
        }
    }

    function output($image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
        if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
            imagejpeg($this->image);
        } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
            imagegif($this->image);
        } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
            imageAlphaBlending($this->image, true);
            imageSaveAlpha($this->image, true);
            imagepng($this->image);
        }   
    }

    function getWidth() {
        return imagesx($this->image);
    }
    function getHeight() {
        return imagesy($this->image);
    }
    function resizeToHeight($height) {
        $ratio = $height / $this->getHeight();
        $width = $this->getWidth() * $ratio;
        $this->resize($width,$height);
    }
    function resizeToWidth($width) {
        $ratio = $width / $this->getWidth();
        $height = $this->getheight() * $ratio;
        $this->resize($width,$height);
    }
    function scale($scale) {
        $width = $this->getWidth() * $scale/100;
        $height = $this->getheight() * $scale/100;
        $this->resize($width,$height);
    }
    function resize($width,$height) {

        // ADDED CODE IS HERE - NOT SURE WHY IT DOESN'T WORK FOR PNG

        // Setup new image
        $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        // These parameters are required for handling PNG files.
        imagealphablending($new_image, false);
        imagesavealpha($new_image,true);
        $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($new_image, 255, 255, 255, 127);
        imagefilledrectangle($new_image, 0, 0, $width, $height, $transparent);
        // Resize image
        imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
        $this->image = $new_image;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Now have the transparency working for PNG but not gif. Here are the edits to the specific functions in case it will help someone else:

Save Function:

```
function save($filename, $image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $compression=75, $permissions=null) {

   // do this or they'll all go to jpeg
   $image_type=$this->image_type;

  if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
     imagejpeg($this->image,$filename,$compression);
  } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
     imagegif($this->image,$filename);  
  } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
    // need this for transparent png to work          
    imagealphablending($this->image, false);
    imagesavealpha($this->image,true);
    imagepng($this->image,$filename);
  }   
  if( $permissions != null) {
     chmod($filename,$permissions);
  }
```

}

Resize Function

```
 function resize($width,$height,$forcesize='n') {

  /* optional. if file is smaller, do not resize. */
  if ($forcesize == 'n') {
      if ($width > $this->getWidth() && $height > $this->getHeight()){
          $width = $this->getWidth();
          $height = $this->getHeight();
      }
  }

  $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
  /* Check if this image is PNG or GIF, then set if Transparent*/  
  if(($this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF) || ($this->image_type==IMAGETYPE_PNG)){
      imagealphablending($new_image, false);
      imagesavealpha($new_image,true);
      $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($new_image, 255, 255, 255, 127);
      imagefilledrectangle($new_image, 0, 0, $width, $height, $transparent);
  }
  imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());

  $this->image = $new_image;
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the code!! It saved me lots of time! i edited a small part of your code because $new_image in save() function is an undefined variable

Answer (score 1):

The function `imagecreatetruecolor()` does not work with GIF's. Use the `imagecreate` method instead:

```
if($this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF){
    $new_image = imagecreate( $Width, $Height ); // for gif files
} else{
    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($Width, $Height); // for all other files
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been playing with GD for a long time myself (I prefer Imagemagick), but you could try setting alpha also to the source image before copying:

```
...
// ADDED CODE IS HERE ..
imagealphablending($this->image, true);
...
```

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried working that in and it didn't work, but may have been where I was trying it. My code above now works for PNG files.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same as in this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6401135/262462 but edited this part

```
function save($filename, $image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $compression=75, $permissions=null) {

// do this or they'll all go to jpeg
$image_type=$this->image_type;
```

to this

```
function save($filename, $image_type="original", $compression=75, $permissions=null) {

    if ($image_type=="original")
        $image_type=$this->image_type;
```