# How to resize the image in php

Tags: php, image-resizing, php-5.2

```html
My Updated code


/*$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$path = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$filename = file_get_contents($path);*/
/*    
$imgdata = base64_encode($im); // here we got base64 encode value

$idproof = array("encode" => $imgdata,
                 "path" =>$path,
                 "extension" =>$extension,
                 );
echo json_encode($idproof);*/

   $image;
   $image_type;
   $width = 150;
   $height = 150;
   //-----------------------------------------------
   //   Load Image file
   //-----------------------------------------------
   function load($filename) 
   {
       global $image;
       global $image_type;

            $image_info = getimagesize($filename);
            $image_type = $image_info[2];
            if($image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) 
            {
                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
            } 
            elseif($image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF) 
            {
                $image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
            }
            elseif($image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG) 
            {
                $image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
            }
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------
   //   Save Image file
   //-----------------------------------------------
   function save($filename, $image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $compression=75, $permissions=null)
   {
       global $image;
       global $image_type;

            if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) 
            {
                imagejpeg($image,$filename,$compression);
            }
            elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF )
            {
                imagegif($image,$filename);
            } 
            elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG )
            {
                imagepng($image,$filename);
            }
            if( $permissions != null ) 
            {
                chmod($filename,$permissions);
            }
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------
   //   View Image file
   //-----------------------------------------------
   function output($image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG) 
   {
      global $image;
      global $image_type;

      if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG )
      {
         imagejpeg($image);
      } 
      elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF )
      {
         imagegif($image);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) 
      {
         imagepng($image);
      }
   }

   function getWidth() 
   {
      global $image;
      return imagesx($image);
   }
   function getHeight() 
   {
      global $image;
      return imagesy($image);
   }

   //=============================================================================
   //   Resize Images
   //=============================================================================

   //-----------------------------------------------
   //   Resize Images 01 - Resize to Height
   //-----------------------------------------------
   function resizeToHeight($height) 
   {
      $ratio = $height / getHeight();
      $width = getWidth() * $ratio;
      resize($width,$height);
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------
   //   Resize Images 02 - Resize to Width
   //-----------------------------------------------
   function resizeToWidth($width) 
   {
      $ratio = $width / getWidth();
      $height = getheight() * $ratio;
      resize($width,$height);
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------
   //   Resize Images 03 - Scale in %
   //-----------------------------------------------
   function scale($scale) 
   {
      $width = getWidth() * $scale/100;
      $height = getheight() * $scale/100;
      resize($width,$height);
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------
   //   Resize Images 04 - Scale in %
   //-----------------------------------------------
   function resize($width,$height) 
   {
      global $image;

      $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
      imagecopyresampled($new_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, getWidth(), getHeight());
      $image = $new_image;
   }     


 load($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

// To resize based on image width
   
 resizeToWidth($width); 

// To resize based on image height
 resizeToHeight($height); 

// To resize to specific size
   resize($width, $height) ;

$filename = base64_encode(output());

$idproof = array("encode" => $filename,
                 );
echo json_encode($idproof);
```

I am doing one php file upload,in that field user uploads the large image means, i want to re size the image,[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382448/png-transparency-resize-with-simpleimage-php-class) i want like this ,but this code i can't understand,next after re size the image  i want to encode that image how can do this one?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#idproof").submit(function(e) {
            var formData = new FormData();
            var id = '<?php echo $id;?>';
            formData.append('ssmid', id);
   formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
              $.ajax({
              url: 'idproof_check.php',
              type: 'POST',
              data: formData,
              async: false,
              cache: false,
              contentType: false,
              processData: false,
              success: function (data) {
                  var res=jQuery.parseJSON(data);// convert the json
                  console.log(res);
              },
             });
             });
</script>


idproof_check.php

<?php
$userid = $_POST['userid'];
 
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$path = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

$im = file_get_contents($path);
/*Here i want to resize the image after that i want to encode the image*/

$filename = base64_encode($im); // here we got base64 encoded value

$idproof = array("encode" => $filename,
                 "path" =>$path,
                 "extension" =>$extension,
                 );
echo json_encode($idproof);

?>
```

```html
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" id="idproof" name="myForm">
   <div class="input-group heading1">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
            Browse&hellip; <input type="file" id="myFile" name="file" >
        </span>
    </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="">
</div>

 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="input-group heading1">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md horoscope">Upload ID Proof</button>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [resize image in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649645/resize-image-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the php class to resize images.

```
    <?php

    /*
    * File: SimpleImage.php
    * Author: Simon Jarvis
    * Copyright: 2006 Simon Jarvis
    * Date: 08/11/06
    * Link: http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/articles/php-image-resizing.php
    *
    * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
    * modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
    * as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
    * of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
    *
    * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
    * GNU General Public License for more details:
    * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
    *
    */

   $image;
   $image_type;

   //-----------------------------------------------
   //   Load Image file
   //-----------------------------------------------
   function load($filename) 
   {
       global $image;
       global $image_type;

            $image_info = getimagesize($filename);
            $image_type = $image_info[2];
            if($image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) 
            {
                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
            } 
            elseif($image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF) 
            {
                $image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
            }
            elseif($image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG) 
            {
                $image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
            }
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------
   //   Save Image file
   //-----------------------------------------------
   function save($filename, $image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $compression=75, $permissions=null)
   {
       global $image;
       global $image_type;

            if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) 
            {
                imagejpeg($image,$filename,$compression);
            }
            elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF )
            {
                imagegif($image,$filename);
            } 
            elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG )
            {
                imagepng($image,$filename);
            }
            if( $permissions != null ) 
            {
                chmod($filename,$permissions);
            }
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------
   //   View Image file
   //-----------------------------------------------
   function output($image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG) 
   {
      global $image;
      global $image_type;

      if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG )
      {
         imagejpeg($image);
      } 
      elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF )
      {
         imagegif($image);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) 
      {
         imagepng($image);
      }
   }

   function getWidth() 
   {
      global $image;
      return imagesx($image);
   }
   function getHeight() 
   {
      global $image;
      return imagesy($image);
   }

   //=============================================================================
   //   Resize Images
   //=============================================================================

   //-----------------------------------------------
   //   Resize Images 01 - Resize to Height
   //-----------------------------------------------
   function resizeToHeight($height) 
   {
      $ratio = $height / getHeight();
      $width = getWidth() * $ratio;
      resize($width,$height);
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------
   //   Resize Images 02 - Resize to Width
   //-----------------------------------------------
   function resizeToWidth($width) 
   {
      $ratio = $width / getWidth();
      $height = getheight() * $ratio;
      resize($width,$height);
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------
   //   Resize Images 03 - Scale in %
   //-----------------------------------------------
   function scale($scale) 
   {
      $width = getWidth() * $scale/100;
      $height = getheight() * $scale/100;
      resize($width,$height);
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------
   //   Resize Images 04 - Scale in %
   //-----------------------------------------------
   function resize($width,$height) 
   {
      global $image;

      $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
      imagecopyresampled($new_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, getWidth(), getHeight());
      $image = $new_image;
   }      
    ?>
```

Call this class using:

```
load($_FILES["IMAGE_FILE"]["tmp_name"]);

// To resize based on image width
resizeToWidth($width); 

// To resize based on image height
resizeToHeight($height); 

// To resize to specific size
resize($width, $height) 

// To save file in web server directory
save($PATH);

// To retrieve resized images directly from variable
output();
```

**EDIT:**
You don't need `echo` to make a function call.

```
$width = 150;
$height = 150;
load($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

// To resize to specific size
resize($width, $height) 

$filename = base64_encode(output());
```

Comment: I am using simple PHP no need to use class how can do?

Comment: Just copy the codes within the `SimpleImage` class and paste it to your PHP file, you can use it as functions.

Comment: Yes, just get those functions out from class.

Comment: Sorry Mr @FrozenFire,edit your code,then i will copy your code and test,bcz i am only 2 months experience of PHP developer

Comment: You can use `output();`, or for your code `$filename = base64_encode(output());`

Comment: i did removed my php code and fully copy your code and paste in my php file,and also call all functions finally $filename = base64_encode(output());

$idproof = array("encode" => $filename,
                 );
echo json_encode($idproof); but i am getting like this error  --->500 Internal Server Error

Comment: @kasthuri S  Sorry I forgot to add `global` in functions. see my updated answer.

Comment: Still i am getting same error, i am calling functions like this echo resizeToWidth($width); 

// To resize based on image height
echo resizeToHeight($height); 

// To resize to specific size
echo resize($width, $height)  FROM HERE $width and $hight what? we can give static or something else ?

Comment: You must call it like this `resizeToWidth($width);` then `echo output();`. Use `output();` when you want to retrieve the image.

Comment: Now i want to base64 code value after that i want insert value in DB,after inserting value only i want retrieve the image

Comment: @kasthuri S  please read my prev. comments. `$filename = base64_encode(output());` will do.

Comment: still am getting same error,Please see my updated code,if i am anything did wrong means inform me

Comment: You don't need to `echo` when making a function call, see my updated answer.

Comment: K but load function you wrote two method load($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

Comment: its depend on the how you've declared `name` in your form. Since you've used `<input type="file" id="myFile" name="Filename" >` it should be Filename (`load($_FILES["Filename"]["tmp_name"]);`) e.g. also need to replace `$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` to `$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['Filename']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

Comment: Please see my code now changed instead of name= Filename(file),give hight and width but like this ------>SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: You're still using `echo` on function call, please read the EDITED part of my answer.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to post this code but remove the echo i am getting same SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: save($PATH);//means what.from here i don't want to move this image in one folder,after encode the value directly insert into DB

Comment: Then don't call `save($PATH);`

Answer (score 0):

Call this function where you insert your image

```
<?php
function make_thumb($src, $dest, $desired_width, $desired_height) {

    /* read the source image */
    $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $width = imagesx($source_image);
    $height = imagesy($source_image);
    /*if($width <600){
    $desired_width = $width;    
    }*/

    /* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width  */


    /* create a new, "virtual" image */
    $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);

    /* copy source image at a resized size */
    imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $width, $height);

    /* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination */
    imagejpeg($virtual_image, $dest);
}


    $src = "../../gallery_image/$file_name";
    $dest = "../../gallery_image/thumb/$file_name";
    $desired_width = "360";
    $desired_height = "260";
    make_thumb($src, $dest, $desired_width, $desired_height);

?>
```