# PHP : Create PNG from multiple files and resize

Tags: php, image, resize, png, gd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I resize pngs with transparency in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279236/how-do-i-resize-pngs-with-transparency-in-php)

I have a script which creates a PNG by combining multiple files:

```
$img_width = 950;
$img_height = 950;
$final_img = imagecreatetruecolor($img_width, $img_height);
imagesavealpha($final_img, true);
$trans_colour = imagecolorallocatealpha($final_img, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($final_img, 0, 0, $trans_colour);

foreach ($images_array as $image) {
    $image_layer = imagecreatefrompng($image);
    imagecopy($final_img, $image_layer, 0, 0, 0, 0, $img_width, $img_height);
}

imagesavealpha($final_img, true);
imagealphablending($final_img, true);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($final_img);
```

All the images I'm combining at 950px square. How can I make it so the returned image is say 200 x 200 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the imagecopyresampled function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php. Specifically see the second example.