# Scale Image Using PHP and Maintaining Aspect Ratio

Tags: php, image, scale

Basically I want to upload an image (which i've sorted) and scale it down to certain constraints such as max width and height but maintain the aspect ratio of the original image.

I don't have Imagick installed on the server - otherwise this would be easy.

Any help is appreciated as always.
Thanks.

EDIT: I don't need the whole code or anything, just a push in the right direction would be fantastic.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had written a peice of code like this for another project I've done. I've copied it below, might need a bit of tinkering! (It does required the GD library)

These are the parameters it needs:

```
$image_name - Name of the image which is uploaded
$new_width - Width of the resized photo (maximum)
$new_height - Height of the resized photo (maximum)
$uploadDir - Directory of the original image
$moveToDir - Directory to save the resized image
```

It will scale down or up an image to the maximum width or height

```
function createThumbnail($image_name,$new_width,$new_height,$uploadDir,$moveToDir)
{
    $path = $uploadDir . '/' . $image_name;

    $mime = getimagesize($path);

    if($mime['mime']=='image/png') { 
        $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($path);
    }
    if($mime['mime']=='image/jpg' || $mime['mime']=='image/jpeg' || $mime['mime']=='image/pjpeg') {
        $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
    }   

    $old_x          =   imageSX($src_img);
    $old_y          =   imageSY($src_img);

    if($old_x > $old_y) 
    {
        $thumb_w    =   $new_width;
        $thumb_h    =   $old_y*($new_height/$old_x);
    }

    if($old_x < $old_y) 
    {
        $thumb_w    =   $old_x*($new_width/$old_y);
        $thumb_h    =   $new_height;
    }

    if($old_x == $old_y) 
    {
        $thumb_w    =   $new_width;
        $thumb_h    =   $new_height;
    }

    $dst_img        =   ImageCreateTrueColor($thumb_w,$thumb_h);

    imagecopyresampled($dst_img,$src_img,0,0,0,0,$thumb_w,$thumb_h,$old_x,$old_y); 


    // New save location
    $new_thumb_loc = $moveToDir . $image_name;

    if($mime['mime']=='image/png') {
        $result = imagepng($dst_img,$new_thumb_loc,8);
    }
    if($mime['mime']=='image/jpg' || $mime['mime']=='image/jpeg' || $mime['mime']=='image/pjpeg') {
        $result = imagejpeg($dst_img,$new_thumb_loc,80);
    }

    imagedestroy($dst_img); 
    imagedestroy($src_img);

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Nice - Thanks very much, that will be usefull. I'm talking to the host to try and get Imagick sorted... getting a fatal error currently where it says its not found the class...

Comment: If you use `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and do a search for GD, if it is enabled, the above function should work, even without imagick :), however, if you get any errors, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting up-votes, I wrote it years ago, recently stumbled upon it while trying to solve the same issue (again) and it didn't keep aspect ratio!

Comment: You surely mean `$thumb_h    =   $old_y*($new_width/$old_x);` and `$thumb_w    =   $old_x*($new_height/$old_y);` when the source image is not a square, this will always resize to the biggest possible thumbnail having `$new_height` as max height and `$new width` as max width

Comment: It almost works but the second part should be changed to
if($old_x < $old_y)
        {
            $thumb_h    =   $newHeight;
            $thumb_w    =   $old_x/$old_y*$newHeight;
        }

Answer (score 26):

Actually the accepted solution it is **not** the correct solution. The reason is simple: there will be cases when the ratio of the source image and the ratio of the destination image will be different. Any calculation should reflect this difference.

Please note the relevant lines from the example given on PHP.net website:

```
$ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {
   $width = $height*$ratio_orig;
} else {
   $height = $width/$ratio_orig;
}
```

The full example may be found here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php

There are other answers (with examples) on stackoverflow to similar questions (the same question formulated in a different manner) that suffer of the same problem.

Example:

Let's say we have an image of 1630 x 2400 pixels that we want to be auto resized keeping the aspect ratio to 160 x 240. Let's do some math taking the accepted solution:

```
if($old_x < $old_y) 
    {
        $thumb_w    =   $old_x*($new_width/$old_y);
        $thumb_h    =   $new_height;
    }
```

height = 240
width = 1630 * ( 160/2400 ) = 1630 * 0.0666666666666667 = 108.6666666666667
108.6 x 240 it's not the correct solution.

The next solution proposed is the following:

```
if($old_x < $old_y)
    {
        $thumb_w    =   $old_x/$old_y*$newHeight;
        $thumb_h    =   $newHeight;
    }
```

height = 240;
width = 1630 / 2400 * 240 = 163
It is better (as it maintain the aspect ratio), but it exceeded the maximum accepted width.

Both fail.

We do the math according to the solution proposed by PHP.net:
width = 160
height = 160/(1630 / 2400) = 160/0.6791666666666667 = 235.5828220858896 (the *else* clause). 160 x 236 (rounded) is the correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

Formule is wrong for keeping aspect ratio.
It should be: original height / original width x new width = new height

```
function createThumbnail($imageName,$newWidth,$newHeight,$uploadDir,$moveToDir)
{
    $path = $uploadDir . '/' . $imageName;

    $mime = getimagesize($path);

    if($mime['mime']=='image/png'){ $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($path); }
    if($mime['mime']=='image/jpg'){ $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($path); }
    if($mime['mime']=='image/jpeg'){ $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($path); }
    if($mime['mime']=='image/pjpeg'){ $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($path); }

    $old_x = imageSX($src_img);
    $old_y = imageSY($src_img);

    if($old_x > $old_y)
    {
        $thumb_w    =   $newWidth;
        $thumb_h    =   $old_y/$old_x*$newWidth;
    }

    if($old_x < $old_y)
    {
        $thumb_w    =   $old_x/$old_y*$newHeight;
        $thumb_h    =   $newHeight;
    }

    if($old_x == $old_y)
    {
        $thumb_w    =   $newWidth;
        $thumb_h    =   $newHeight;
    }

    $dst_img        =   ImageCreateTrueColor($thumb_w,$thumb_h);

    imagecopyresampled($dst_img,$src_img,0,0,0,0,$thumb_w,$thumb_h,$old_x,$old_y);


    // New save location
    $new_thumb_loc = $moveToDir . $imageName;

    if($mime['mime']=='image/png'){ $result = imagepng($dst_img,$new_thumb_loc,8); }
    if($mime['mime']=='image/jpg'){ $result = imagejpeg($dst_img,$new_thumb_loc,80); }
    if($mime['mime']=='image/jpeg'){ $result = imagejpeg($dst_img,$new_thumb_loc,80); }
    if($mime['mime']=='image/pjpeg'){ $result = imagejpeg($dst_img,$new_thumb_loc,80); }

    imagedestroy($dst_img);
    imagedestroy($src_img);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Just, it does not keep aspect ratio. If I want to resize a 300x300 image to an 500x200, it will create an 500x200.

Answer (score 3):

I was thinking about how to achieve this and i came with a pretty nice solution that works in any case...
Lets say you want to resize  heavy images that users upload to your site but you need it to maintain the ratio. So i came up with this :

```
<?php
// File 
$filename = 'test.jpg';



// Get sizes
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
//obtain ratio
$imageratio = $width/$height;

if($imageratio >= 1){
    $newwidth = 600;
    $newheight = 600 / $imageratio; 
}
else{
     $newidth = 400;
     $newheight = 400 / $imageratio;
};




// Load
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Resize
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, 
$height);

// Output
imagejpeg($thumb, "img/test.jpg");
imagedestroy();
?>
```

In this case if width is bigger than height, i wanted the width to be 600px and if the height was bigger than the width, i wanted the width to be 400px

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
Class ResizedImage
{
    public $imgfile;
    public $string      = '';
    public $new_width   = 0;
    public $new_height  = 0;
    public $angle       = 0;
    public $max_font_size = 1000;
    public $cropped = false;//whether crop the original image if h or w > new h or w
    public $font = 'fonts/arialbd.ttf';

    private $img;
    private $trans_colour;
    private $orange;
    private $white; 
    private $whitetr;
    private $blacktr;

    public function PrintAsBase64()
    {
        $this->SetImage();
        ob_start();
        imagepng($this->img);
        $b64img = ob_get_contents();
        ob_clean();
        imagedestroy($this->img);
        $b64img = base64_encode($b64img);
        echo($b64img);
    }
    public function PrintAsImage()
    {
        $this->SetImage();

        header('Content-type: image/png');

        imagepng($this->img);
        imagedestroy($this->img);
    }

    private function SetImage()
    {
        if ($this->imgfile == '') {$this->imgfile='NoImageAvailable.jpg';}
        $this->img          = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($this->imgfile));
        $this->trans_colour = imagecolorallocatealpha($this->img, 0, 0, 0, 127);
        $this->orange       = imagecolorallocate($this->img, 220, 210, 60);
        $this->white        = imagecolorallocate($this->img, 255,255, 255);
        $this->whitetr      = imagecolorallocatealpha($this->img, 255,255, 255, 95);
        $this->blacktr      = imagecolorallocatealpha($this->img, 0, 0, 0, 95);

        if ((!$this->cropped) && ($this->string !=''))
        {$this->watermarkimage();}

        if (($this->new_height > 0) && ($this->new_width > 0)) {$this->ResizeImage();};

        if (($this->cropped) && ($this->string !=''))
        {$this->watermarkimage();}

        imageAlphaBlending($this->img, true);
        imageSaveAlpha($this->img, true);
    }
    ////
    private function ResizeImage()
    {
        # v_fact and h_fact are the factor by which the original vertical / horizontal
        # image sizes should be multiplied to get the image to your target size.
        $v_fact = $this->new_height / imagesy($this->img);//target_height / im_height; 
        $h_fact = $this->new_width / imagesx($this->img);//target_width / im_width;
        # you want to resize the image by the same factor in both vertical 
        # and horizontal direction, so you need to pick the correct factor from
        # v_fact / h_fact so that the largest (relative to target) of the new height/width
        # equals the target height/width and the smallest is lower than the target.
        # this is the lowest of the two factors
        if($this->cropped) 
        {   $im_fact = max($v_fact, $h_fact);   }
        else
        {   $im_fact = min($v_fact, $h_fact);   }

        $new_height = round(imagesy($this->img) * $im_fact);
        $new_width  = round(imagesx($this->img) * $im_fact);

        $img2 = $this->img;     
        $this->img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);     
        imagecopyresampled($this->img, $img2, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, imagesx($img2), imagesy($img2));

        $img2 = $this->img;     
        $this->img = imagecreatetruecolor($this->new_width, $this->new_height);
        imagefill($this->img, 0, 0, $this->trans_colour);

        $dstx = 0;
        $dsty = 0;
        if ($this->cropped)
        {
            if (imagesx($this->img) < imagesx($img2))
            {   $dstx = round((imagesx($this->img)-imagesx($img2))/2); }

            if (imagesy($this->img) < imagesy($img2))
            {   $dsty = round((imagesy($this->img)-imagesy($img2))/2); }
        }
        else
        {
            if (imagesx($this->img) > imagesx($img2))
            {   $dstx = round((imagesx($this->img)-imagesx($img2))/2); }

            if (imagesy($this->img) > imagesy($img2))
            {   $dsty = round((imagesy($this->img)-imagesy($img2))/2); }
        }

        imagecopy ( $this->img, $img2, $dstx, $dsty, 0, 0, imagesx($img2) , imagesy($img2));
        imagedestroy($img2);        
    }   

    ////

    private function calculateTextBox($text,$fontFile,$fontSize,$fontAngle) 
    { 
        /************ 
        simple function that calculates the *exact* bounding box (single pixel precision). 
        The function returns an associative array with these keys: 
        left, top:  coordinates you will pass to imagettftext 
        width, height: dimension of the image you have to create 
        *************/ 
        $rect = imagettfbbox($fontSize,$fontAngle,$fontFile,$text); 
        $minX = min(array($rect[0],$rect[2],$rect[4],$rect[6])); 
        $maxX = max(array($rect[0],$rect[2],$rect[4],$rect[6])); 
        $minY = min(array($rect[1],$rect[3],$rect[5],$rect[7])); 
        $maxY = max(array($rect[1],$rect[3],$rect[5],$rect[7])); 

        return array( 
        "left"   => abs($minX) - 1, 
        "top"    => abs($minY) - 1, 
        "width"  => $maxX - $minX, 
        "height" => $maxY - $minY,
        "box"    => $rect ); 
    }

    private function watermarkimage($font_size=0)
    {
        if ($this->string == '')
        {die('Watermark function call width empty string!');}

        $box = $this->calculateTextBox($this->string, $this->font, $font_size, $this->angle);
        while ( ($box['width'] < imagesx($this->img)) && ($box['height'] < imagesy($this->img)) && ($font_size <= $this->max_font_size) )
        {
            $font_size++;
            $box = $this->calculateTextBox($this->string, $this->font, $font_size, $this->angle);   
        }

        $font_size--;
        $box = $this->calculateTextBox($this->string, $this->font, $font_size, $this->angle);

        $vcenter = round((imagesy($this->img) / 2) + ($box['height'] / 2));  
        $hcenter = round((imagesx($this->img) - $box['width']) / 2 );

        imagettftext($this->img, $font_size, $this->angle, $hcenter, $vcenter, $this->blacktr, $this->font, $this->string);     
        imagettftext($this->img, $font_size, $this->angle, $hcenter+1, $vcenter-2, $this->whitetr, $this->font, $this->string);
    }
}
?>
```

Also I have been using the accepted answer but it does not keep the ratio in some cases. I have found some good answers on the forum and have put them in together and finally created a Class which resizes an image. As extra function u can put a watermark text.

u can see what happens when choose to crop or not, if not a transparent area will be added to the new resized image.

This example is more than asked, but I think it is a good example.

Comment: this seems to be a good function and works as intended, but what if I want to crop always.. for example my destination image is 500 400 then:
//W400 H300 = stretchW | stretchH
//W400 H500 = stretchW+H at first then crop H
//W500 H300 = stretch W+H at first then crop W
//W500 H500 = cropW | cropH

Comment: I did not clearly understand your point but, the function works. u can choose to crop or not. Set the default value to "true" when u use the function on your page. If u can make it work better with some changes u are welcome.
BTW I am not a php/web master, just a hobbyist.

Answer (score 1):

I found a mathematical way to get this job done

Github repo - https://github.com/gayanSandamal/easy-php-image-resizer

Live example - https://plugins.nayague.com/easy-php-image-resizer/

```
<?php
//path for the image
$source_url = '2018-04-01-1522613288.PNG';

//separate the file name and the extention
$source_url_parts = pathinfo($source_url);
$filename = $source_url_parts['filename'];
$extension = $source_url_parts['extension'];

//define the quality from 1 to 100
$quality = 10;

//detect the width and the height of original image
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($source_url);
$width;
$height;

//define any width that you want as the output. mine is 200px.
$after_width = 200;

//resize only when the original image is larger than expected with.
//this helps you to avoid from unwanted resizing.
if ($width > $after_width) {

    //get the reduced width
    $reduced_width = ($width - $after_width);
    //now convert the reduced width to a percentage and round it to 2 decimal places
    $reduced_radio = round(($reduced_width / $width) * 100, 2);

    //ALL GOOD! let's reduce the same percentage from the height and round it to 2 decimal places
    $reduced_height = round(($height / 100) * $reduced_radio, 2);
    //reduce the calculated height from the original height
    $after_height = $height - $reduced_height;

    //Now detect the file extension
    //if the file extension is 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'JPG' or 'JPEG'
    if ($extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'jpeg' || $extension == 'JPG' || $extension == 'JPEG') {
        //then return the image as a jpeg image for the next step
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);
    } elseif ($extension == 'png' || $extension == 'PNG') {
        //then return the image as a png image for the next step
        $img = imagecreatefrompng($source_url);
    } else {
        //show an error message if the file extension is not available
        echo 'image extension is not supporting';
    }

    //HERE YOU GO :)
    //Let's do the resize thing
    //imagescale([returned image], [width of the resized image], [height of the resized image], [quality of the resized image]);
    $imgResized = imagescale($img, $after_width, $after_height, $quality);

    //now save the resized image with a suffix called "-resized" and with its extension. 
    imagejpeg($imgResized, $filename . '-resized.'.$extension);

    //Finally frees any memory associated with image
    //**NOTE THAT THIS WONT DELETE THE IMAGE
    imagedestroy($img);
    imagedestroy($imgResized);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my function to scale an image with save aspect ration for X, Y or both axes.

It's also scales an image for percent of it size.

*Compatibe with PHP 5.4*

```php
/** Use X axis to scale image. */
define('IMAGES_SCALE_AXIS_X', 1);
/** Use Y axis to scale image. */
define('IMAGES_SCALE_AXIS_Y', 2);
/** Use both X and Y axes to calc image scale. */
define('IMAGES_SCALE_AXIS_BOTH', IMAGES_SCALE_AXIS_X ^ IMAGES_SCALE_AXIS_Y);
/** Compression rate for JPEG image format. */
define('JPEG_COMPRESSION_QUALITY', 90);
/** Compression rate for PNG image format. */
define('PNG_COMPRESSION_QUALITY', 9);

/**
 * Scales an image with save aspect ration for X, Y or both axes.
 *
 * @param string $sourceFile Absolute path to source image.
 * @param string $destinationFile Absolute path to scaled image.
 * @param int|null $toWidth Maximum `width` of scaled image.
 * @param int|null $toHeight Maximum `height` of scaled image.
 * @param int|null $percent Percent of scale of the source image's size.
 * @param int $scaleAxis Determines how of axis will be used to scale image.
 *
 * May take a value of {@link IMAGES_SCALE_AXIS_X}, {@link IMAGES_SCALE_AXIS_Y} or {@link IMAGES_SCALE_AXIS_BOTH}.
 * @return bool True on success or False on failure.
 */
function scaleImage($sourceFile, $destinationFile, $toWidth = null, $toHeight = null, $percent = null, $scaleAxis = IMAGES_SCALE_AXIS_BOTH) {
    $toWidth = (int)$toWidth;
    $toHeight = (int)$toHeight;
    $percent = (int)$percent;
    $result = false;

    if (($toWidth | $toHeight | $percent)
        && file_exists($sourceFile)
        && (file_exists(dirname($destinationFile)) || mkdir(dirname($destinationFile), 0777, true))) {

        $mime = getimagesize($sourceFile);

        if (in_array($mime['mime'], ['image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg'])) {
            $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($sourceFile);
        } elseif ($mime['mime'] == 'image/png') {
            $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($sourceFile);
        }

        $original_width = imagesx($src_img);
        $original_height = imagesy($src_img);

        if ($scaleAxis == IMAGES_SCALE_AXIS_BOTH) {
            if (!($toWidth | $percent)) {
                $scaleAxis = IMAGES_SCALE_AXIS_Y;
            } elseif (!($toHeight | $percent)) {
                $scaleAxis = IMAGES_SCALE_AXIS_X;
            }
        }

        if ($scaleAxis == IMAGES_SCALE_AXIS_X && $toWidth) {
            $scale_ratio = $original_width / $toWidth;
        } elseif ($scaleAxis == IMAGES_SCALE_AXIS_Y && $toHeight) {
            $scale_ratio = $original_height / $toHeight;
        } elseif ($percent) {
            $scale_ratio = 100 / $percent;
        } else {
            $scale_ratio_width = $original_width / $toWidth;
            $scale_ratio_height = $original_height / $toHeight;

            if ($original_width / $scale_ratio_width < $toWidth && $original_height / $scale_ratio_height < $toHeight) {
                $scale_ratio = min($scale_ratio_width, $scale_ratio_height);
            } else {
                $scale_ratio = max($scale_ratio_width, $scale_ratio_height);
            }
        }

        $scale_width = $original_width / $scale_ratio;
        $scale_height = $original_height / $scale_ratio;

        $dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor($scale_width, $scale_height);

        imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $scale_width, $scale_height, $original_width, $original_height);

        if (in_array($mime['mime'], ['image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg'])) {
            $result = imagejpeg($dst_img, $destinationFile, JPEG_COMPRESSION_QUALITY);
        } elseif ($mime['mime'] == 'image/png') {
            $result = imagepng($dst_img, $destinationFile, PNG_COMPRESSION_QUALITY);
        }

        imagedestroy($dst_img);
        imagedestroy($src_img);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Tests:

```php
$sourceFile = '/source/file.jpg'; // Original size: 672x100
$destinationPath = '/destination/path/';

scaleImage($sourceFile, $destinationPath . 'file_original_size.jpg', 672, 100);
// Result: Image 672x100
scaleImage($sourceFile, $destinationPath . 'file_scaled_75_PERCENT.jpg', null, null, 75);
// Result: Image 504x75
scaleImage($sourceFile, $destinationPath . 'file_scaled_336_X.jpg', 336, null, null, IMAGES_SCALE_AXIS_X);
// Result: Image 336x50
scaleImage($sourceFile, $destinationPath . 'file_scaled_50_Y.jpg', null, 50, null, IMAGES_SCALE_AXIS_Y);
// Result: Image 336x50
scaleImage($sourceFile, $destinationPath . 'file_scaled_500x70_BOTH.jpg', 500, 70, null, IMAGES_SCALE_AXIS_BOTH);
// Result: Image 470x70
scaleImage($sourceFile, $destinationPath . 'file_scaled_450x70_BOTH.jpg', 450, 70, null, IMAGES_SCALE_AXIS_BOTH);
// Result: Image 450x66
scaleImage($sourceFile, $destinationPath . 'file_scaled_500x70_40_PERCENT_BOTH.jpg', 500, 70, 40, IMAGES_SCALE_AXIS_BOTH);
// Result: Image 268x40
```

Comment: Good but this doen't preserve transparency for PNG. To scale with transparency: https://stackoverflow.com/a/279310/5078983

Answer (score 0):

Here is a comprehensive application that I worked hard on it to include most common operations like scale up & scale down, thumbnail, preserve aspect ratio, convert file type, change quality/file size and more...

```
<?php
//##// Resize (and convert) image (Scale up & scale down, thumbnail, preserve aspect ratio) //##//
///////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////// Begin.Setup /////////////////
// Source File:
$src_file = "/your/server/path/to/file.png";// png or jpg files only

// Resize Dimensions:
// leave blank for no size change (convert only)
// if you specify one dimension, the other dimension will be calculated according to the aspect ratio
// if you specify both dimensions system will take care of it depending on the actual image size 
// $newWidth = 2000;
// $newHeight = 1500;

// Destination Path: (optional, if none: download image)
$dst_path = "/your/server/path/new/";

// Destination File Name: (Leave blank for same file name)
// $dst_name = 'image_name_only_no_extension';

// Destination File Type: (Leave blank for same file extension)
// $dst_type = 'png';
$dst_type = 'jpg';

// Reduce to 8bit - 256 colors (Very low quality but very small file & transparent PNG. Only for thumbnails!)
// $palette_8bit = true;

///////////////// End.Setup /////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////
if (!$dst_name){$dst_name = strtolower(pathinfo($src_file, PATHINFO_FILENAME));}
if (!$dst_type){$dst_type = strtolower(pathinfo($src_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));}
if ($palette_8bit){$dst_type = 'png';}
if ($dst_path){$dst_file = $dst_path . $dst_name . '.' . $dst_type;}

$mime = getimagesize($src_file);// Get image dimensions and type

// Destination File Parameters:
if ($dst_type == 'png'){
    $dst_content = 'image/png';
    $quality = 9;// All same quality! 0 too big file // 0(no comp.)-9 (php default: 6)
} elseif ($dst_type == 'jpg'){
    $dst_content = 'image/jpg';
    $quality = 85;// 30 Min. 60 Mid. 85 Cool. 90 Max. (100 Full) // 0-100 (php default: 75)
} else {
    exit('Unknown Destination File Type');
}

// Source File Parameters:
if ($mime['mime']=='image/png'){$src_img = imagecreatefrompng($src_file);}
elseif ($mime['mime']=='image/jpg'){$src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($src_file);}
elseif ($mime['mime']=='image/jpeg'){$src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($src_file);}
elseif ($mime['mime']=='image/pjpeg'){$src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($src_file);}
else {exit('Unknown Source File Type');}

// Define Dimensions:
$old_x = imageSX($src_img);
$old_y = imageSY($src_img);

if ($newWidth AND $newHeight){
    if($old_x > $old_y){
        $new_x    =   $newWidth;
        $new_y    =   $old_y / $old_x * $newWidth;
    } elseif($old_x < $old_y){
        $new_y    =   $newHeight;
        $new_x    =   $old_x / $old_y * $newHeight;
    } elseif($old_x == $old_y){
        $new_x    =   $newWidth;
        $new_y    =   $newHeight;
    }
} elseif ($newWidth){
    $new_x    =   $newWidth;
    $new_y    =   $old_y / $old_x * $newWidth;
} elseif ($newHeight){
    $new_y    =   $newHeight;
    $new_x    =   $old_x / $old_y * $newHeight;
} else {
    $new_x    =   $old_x;
    $new_y    =   $old_y;
}

$dst_img = ImageCreateTrueColor($new_x, $new_y);

if ($palette_8bit){//////// Reduce to 8bit - 256 colors ////////
    $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($dst_img, 255, 255, 255, 127); 
    imagecolortransparent($dst_img, $transparent);
    imagefill($dst_img, 0, 0, $transparent);
    imagecopyresampled($dst_img,$src_img,0,0,0,0,$new_x,$new_y,$old_x,$old_y);// Great quality resize.
    imagetruecolortopalette($dst_img, false, 255);
    imagesavealpha($dst_img, true);
} else {
    // Check image and set transparent for png or white background for jpg
    if ($dst_type == 'png'){
        imagealphablending($dst_img, false);
        imagesavealpha($dst_img, true);
        $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($dst_img, 255, 255, 255, 127);
        imagefilledrectangle($dst_img, 0, 0, $new_x, $new_y, $transparent);
    } elseif ($dst_type == 'jpg'){
        $white = imagecolorallocate($dst_img, 255, 255, 255);
        imagefilledrectangle($dst_img, 0, 0, $new_x, $new_y, $white);
    }

    imagecopyresampled($dst_img,$src_img,0,0,0,0,$new_x,$new_y,$old_x,$old_y);// Great quality resize.
}

// Skip the save to parameter using NULL, then set the quality; imagejpeg($dst_img);=> Default quality
if ($dst_file){
    if ($dst_type == 'png'){
        imagepng($dst_img, $dst_file, $quality);
    } elseif ($dst_type == 'jpg'){
        imagejpeg($dst_img, $dst_file, $quality);
    }
} else {
    header('Content-Disposition: Attachment;filename=' . $dst_name . '.' . $dst_type);// comment this line to show image in browser instead of download
    header('Content-type: ' . $dst_content);
    if ($dst_type == 'png'){
        imagepng($dst_img, NULL, $quality);
    } elseif ($dst_type == 'jpg'){
        imagejpeg($dst_img, NULL, $quality);
    }
}
imagedestroy($src_img);
imagedestroy($dst_img);
//##// END : Resize image (Scale Up & Down) (thumbnail, bigger image, preserve aspect ratio) END //##//
```

Comment: This is a very advanced script I worked hard on to cover the most and perfect it. I noticed a downvote, have you actually tried it? Let me know if something is wrong about it....

Comment: After a couple of years, I used your formula to keep aspect ratio and its worked, upvote. 
About the whole snippet I don't see a reason for why someone downvoted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**works perfecly for me**

```
    static function getThumpnail($file){

    $THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH  = 150; # exmpl.
    $THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT = 150;

    $src_size = filesize($file);
    $filename = basename($file);

    list($src_width, $src_height, $src_type) = getimagesize($file);
    $src_im = false;
    switch ($src_type) {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF  : $src_im = imageCreateFromGif($file);  break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG : $src_im = imageCreateFromJpeg($file); break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG  : $src_im = imageCreateFromPng($file);  break;
        case IMAGETYPE_WBMP  : $src_im = imagecreatefromwbmp($file);  break;
    }   
    if ($src_im === false) { return false; }

    $src_aspect_ratio = $src_width / $src_height;
    $thu_aspect_ratio = $THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH / $THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT;

    if ($src_width <= $THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH && $src_height <= $THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT) {
        $thu_width  = $src_width;
        $thu_height = $src_height;
    } elseif ($thu_aspect_ratio > $src_aspect_ratio) {
        $thu_width  = (int) ($THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT * $src_aspect_ratio);
        $thu_height = $THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT;
    } else {
        $thu_width = $THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH;
        $thu_height = (int) ($THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH / $src_aspect_ratio);
    }

    $thu_im = imagecreatetruecolor($thu_width, $thu_height);
    imagecopyresampled($thu_im, $src_im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thu_width, $thu_height, $src_width, $src_height);

    $dst_im    = imagecreatetruecolor($THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH,$THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH);
    $backcolor = imagecolorallocate($dst_im,192,192,192);
    imagefill($dst_im,0,0,$backcolor);
    imagecopy($dst_im, $thu_im, (imagesx($dst_im)/2)-(imagesx($thu_im)/2), (imagesy($dst_im)/2)-(imagesy($thu_im)/2), 0, 0, imagesx($thu_im), imagesy($thu_im));
    imagedestroy($src_im);
    imagedestroy($thu_im);
    }
```