# Resize images with transparency in php

Tags: php, resize, png, gd, alpha

I have looked all over for how to correctly manage alpha when I'm resizing a png. I've managed to get it to keep transparency, but only for pixels that are completely transparent. Here's my code:

```
$src_image = imagecreatefrompng($file_dir.$this->file_name);
$dst_image = imagecreatetruecolor($this->new_image_width, $this->new_image_height);
imagealphablending($dst_image, true);
imagesavealpha($dst_image, true);
$black = imagecolorallocate($dst_image, 0, 0, 0);
imagecolortransparent($dst_image, $black);
imagecopyresampled($dst_image, $src_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $this->new_image_width, 
                 $this->new_image_height, $this->image_width, $this->image_height);
imagepng($dst_image, $file_dir.$this->file_name);
```

Starting with this source image:

[image]

The resized image looks like this:

[image]

The solution for almost every forum post I've looked at about this issue say to do something like this:

```
imagealphablending($dst_image, false);
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($dst_image, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($dst_image, 0, 0, $transparent);
```

The results from this code fails at saving any alpha whatsoever:

[image]

Is there any other solution? Am I missing something with the alpha blending? Why would that work for everyone else, yet utterly fail for me? I'm using MAMP 2.1.3 and PHP 5.3.15.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resize pngs with transparency in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279236/how-do-i-resize-pngs-with-transparency-in-php)

Comment: I have tried the solutions given in that post (and many others). They have not worked at all and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 12):

```
"They have not worked at all and I'm not sure why."
```

Well you must have been doing something wrong. The code from the linked duplicate with a couple of lines added to load and save the image:

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng(PATH_TO_ROOT."var/tmp/7Nsft.png");

$srcWidth = imagesx($im);
$srcHeight = imagesy($im);

$nWidth = intval($srcWidth / 4);
$nHeight = intval($srcHeight /4);

$newImg = imagecreatetruecolor($nWidth, $nHeight);
imagealphablending($newImg, false);
imagesavealpha($newImg,true);
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($newImg, 255, 255, 255, 127);
imagefilledrectangle($newImg, 0, 0, $nWidth, $nHeight, $transparent);
imagecopyresampled($newImg, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nWidth, $nHeight,
    $srcWidth, $srcHeight);

imagepng($newImg, PATH_TO_ROOT."var/tmp/newTest.png");
```

Produces the image:

[image: A resized PNG with transparency]

i.e. this question (and answer) are a complete duplicate.

Comment: What platform, version of PHP / GD / Imagemagick do you both have? This is probably the cause.

Alternatively, stack overflow could be reprocessing the source image so you are not testing the same image.

Answer (score -2):

i have used simpleImage class for resizing image.
You can re-size your image with maintaining aspect ratio.
this class is using **imagecreatetruecolor**  and **imagecopyresampled** core Php functions to re-size image

```
  $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
  imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
  $this->image = $new_image;
```

find complete code at http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/

Comment: This is not a question, but it is offtopic since asker is specifically targeting PHP's built-in GD library... (this should be comment, not answer)