# Transparency in PNG recognized in some apps but not others

Tags: png, transparency

I have a png image, which you can see here:

http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/9145/archer5.png

The background of the sprite is transparent, I see this on all my browsers and in infranview (which I used to create this), and gimp and windows explorer.

However in Photoshop, Paint, and most importantly PHP GD there is a solid background. Check out the image with one of those applications to see what I'm talking about.

The thumbnails produced on my server are all solid background, not good.

What can I do to make the transparency be recognized by all applications?

Thanks.

Note: I also have 2000 of these images that needs to undergo the same operation. Any batch suggestion would be great as well.

Edit: Sorry guys I apologize for my ineptness! WRONG FILE!
I updated the link with the correct file, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's transparent for me too.

MS Paint doesn't support transparency

As you mention PHP GD check this links

[Preserve PNG image transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32243/can-png-image-transparency-be-preserved-when-using-phps-gdlib-imagecopyresampled)

[Resize and Compose Transparent PNG with PHP](http://alexle.net/archives/131)

[imagecolortransparent PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.imagecolortransparent.php)

[imagealphablending PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.imagealphablending.php)

[imagesavealpha PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.imagesavealpha.php)

Comment: Sorry, I linked the wrong image! Please look at the image again, sorry!

Answer (score 3):

It has a transparent background in Photoshop for me. I'm guessing that if it isn't transparent in some application, it is a problem with the application (not supporting transparency) than with the file.

Answer (score 1):

GD requires one of various options (either directly or in the image type when you create a new image) in order to output transparent pixels.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the applications themselves. When you say PHP GD I think what you really mean is "Internet Explorer" (since PHP is not a viewer). Internet Explorer (at least up to IE7) doesn't do transparent PNG (it puts a grey image behind) unless you do some quirky bullshit with an Alpha filter.

This is your (updated) image in safari (which supports PNG correctly):
[image]
<sub>(source: [arc.net.au](http://www.test.dev.arc.net.au/images/alpha_png.png))</sub>

Comment: No, I really do mean PHP GD. I use Opera, FF, IE, Chrome, etc, all displays the transparency correctly. Photoshop does not. After resizing by PHP GD the background is a solid color.

I think the issue is with the image.

Thanks!

Comment: fair enough, I didn't grep the part of your question where you said it worked in all your browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try saving them as 24-bit PNGs, instead of 32-bit.  Maybe PHP GD would have better support for that.

Comment: 24-bit doesn't have alpha transparency