# Output PNG images with transparency in PHP

Tags: php, image, transparency, effects

How do you correctly output PNG images with PHP so their shading, and other transparent effects don't fail.

[image]

seems to be outputting as

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoIdy.png]

...is there a way so this doesn't happen?

I merged two images together.

```
<?php
// Create image instances
$dest = imagecreatefrompng('vinyl.png');
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg('cover2.jpg');

// Copy and merge
imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 10, 10, 0, 0, 180, 180, 100);

// Output and free from memory
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dest);

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
?>
```

Comment: Are you using the gd lib? If so try imagick and tell me how it goes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`imagealphablending`](http://php.net/manual/function.imagealphablending.php) and [`imagesavealpha`](http://php.net/manual/function.imagesavealpha.php).

Answer (score 0):

See this post: [PNG Image Transparency in PHP GD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32243/can-png-image-transparency-be-preserved-when-using-phps-gdlib-imagecopyresampled)