# Resizing PNG in CodeIgniter while preserving the transparency

Tags: php, codeigniter, resize, transparency, gd

I'm using this code to resize images in CodeIgniter

```
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config['source_image'] = $tempFile;
$config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config['width'] = 70 / $ratio;
$config['height'] = 70;
$config['thumb_marker'] = '';
$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
$this->image_lib->resize();
```

But when I upload png files the transparent area is getting black.
I need to make the resized image transparent. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three first results in google:
http://www.akemapa.com/2008/07/10/php-gd-resize-transparent-image-png-gif/
http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=232090.0
[How to preserve transparency when resizing PNG using Perl and GD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900766/how-to-preserve-transparency-when-resizing-png-using-perl-and-gd)

Specific for CI:
http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/62955/

Comment: in this way the picture gets low quality, any solution for that issue?

Answer (score 3):

Above link is dead since CI got moved. New link here:
http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-7857.html