# Watermark image with opacity

Tags: php, gd, opacity

I am trying to add a watermark to an image using PHP and the GD image library. I can apply the watermark where I specify with the correct opacity setting.

The problem is that my watermark itself has a transparent background. When I try to apply this watermark to the image I get a black background.

The image which the watermark is being applied to is a jpeg. Could this be the problem? If so how would I convert the jpeg into a format which supports transparency, apply watermark, then convert it back?

This is the key bit of code I have at the moment.

```
// Determine image size and type
$size = getimagesize($this->image_path);
$size_x = $size[0];
$size_y = $size[1];
$image_type = $size[2]; // This is always a JPEG

// load source image
$image = $this->ImageCreateFromType($image_type, $this->image_path);

// Determine watermark size and type
$wsize = getimagesize($watermark_path);
$watermark_x = $wsize[0];
$watermark_y = $wsize[1];
$watermark_type = $wsize[2]; // This is typically a PNG

// load watermark
$watermark = $this->ImageCreateFromType($watermark_type, $watermark_path);

$dest_x = $this->setX($size_x, $watermark_x);
$dest_y = $this->setY($size_y, $watermark_y);

imagecopymerge($image, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_x, $watermark_y, $this->opacity);
```

While not really relevant, here is the code for the ImageCreateFromType function

```
function ImageCreateFromType($type,$filename) {
 $im = null;
 switch ($type) {
   case 1:
     $im = ImageCreateFromGif($filename);
     break;
   case 2:
     $im = ImageCreateFromJpeg($filename);
     break;
   case 3:
     $im = ImageCreateFromPNG($filename);
     imagealphablending($im, true);
     imagesavealpha($im, true);
     break;
  }
  return $im;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a read about the imagecolortransparent() function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolortransparent.php

You may also want to look at this question: [Can PNG image transparency be preserved when using PHP's GDlib imagecopyresampled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32243/can-png-image-transparency-be-preserved-when-using-ph)

Answer (score 0):

What I found that works the most is the following solution:

```php
$image_url = "The url of my image";
$watermark_image_url= "The url of my watermark image";
$watermark_image_size = 40; // percent of size relatively to the target image
$watermark_opacity = 50; // opacity 0-100

$im = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($image_url));
$stamp = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($watermark_image_url));

$margin_right = 10;
$margin_bottom = 10;

$stamp_w = imagesx($stamp);
$stamp_h = imagesy($stamp);

// Change the size of the watermark image
$percent_size = $watermark_image_size;
$percent_stamp_w = (int)($stamp_w * $percent_size / 100);
$percent_stamp_h = (int)($stamp_h * $percent_size / 100);

$stamp_imgResized = imagescale($stamp , $percent_stamp_w, $percent_stamp_h);

$opacity = (float)(watermark_opacity / 100);
$final_opacity = 127 - (int)(127*$opacity);

imagealphablending($stamp_imgResized, false);
imagesavealpha($stamp_imgResized, true);

imagefilter($stamp_imgResized, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 0,0,0,$final_opacity); // the fourth parameter is alpha       

imagecopy($im, $stamp_imgResized, $margin_right, $margin_bottom, 0, 0, $percent_stamp_w, $percent_stamp_h);

// output to file
if (str_contains($thumbnail_image, '.png'))
{
    imagepng($im, $output);
} else if (str_contains($thumbnail_image, '.jpg'))
{
    imagejpeg($im, $output);
}
```

It also works with images that already have a transparent background, such as a logo image for example.