# Opacity effect using PHP GD extension

Tags: php, gd

I wonder if it is possible to have "opacity" effect when drawing images on top of other images with the PHP GD extension? Are there any built-in functions that can get the results I want or do I have to go for my own implementation using `imagesetpixel` way?

A pseudo-code to illustrate what I am trying to do right now:

```
// Background image
$image_bg = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);
imagesavealpha($image_bg, true);

// Making background image fully transparent
imagefill($image_bg, 0, 0, imagecolorallocatealpha($image_bg, 0, 0, 0, 127));

// Now the actual image I want to draw with opacity (true color PNG)
$image = imagecreatefrompng(...);

// Drawing with 50 "merge" value
imagecopymerge($image_bg, $image, ..., 50);
```

The trouble with above code is that `imagecopymerge` will not respect background image alpha value and will merge the image with the background as if it was opaque black color (the resulting image will not be 50% transparent).

**Edit:** I ended up implementing my own function using `imagecolorat` and `imagesetpixel` way.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to make a semi transparent watermark image on top of another.

And after striving a little with this, I came up with the following solution.

```php
$image_url = "url of my image";
$watermark_image_url= "url of my watermark image";
$watermark_image_size = 30; // percent of size relatively to the target image
$watermark_opacity = 60; // opacity 0-100

$im = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($image_url));
$stamp = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($watermark_image_url));

$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;

$stamp_w = imagesx($stamp);
$stamp_h = imagesy($stamp);

// Change the size of the watermark image
$percent_size = $watermark_image_size;
$percent_stamp_w = (int)($stamp_w * $percent_size / 100);
$percent_stamp_h = (int)($stamp_h * $percent_size / 100);

$stamp_imgResized = imagescale($stamp , $percent_stamp_w, $percent_stamp_h);

$opacity = (float)(watermark_opacity / 100);
$final_opacity = 127 - (int)(127*$opacity);

imagealphablending($stamp_imgResized, false);
imagesavealpha($stamp_imgResized, true);

imagefilter($stamp_imgResized, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 0,0,0,$final_opacity); // the fourth parameter is alpha       

imagecopy($im, $stamp_imgResized, $marge_right, $marge_bottom, 0, 0, $percent_stamp_w, $percent_stamp_h);

// output to file
if (str_contains($thumbnail_image, '.png'))
{
    imagepng($im, $output);
} else if (str_contains($thumbnail_image, '.jpg'))
{
    imagejpeg($im, $output);
}
```

The following for some reason are required in order for the transperancy to work

```
imagealphablending($stamp_imgResized, false);
imagesavealpha($stamp_imgResized, true);
```

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at [imagecolortransparent()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolortransparent.php) and [imagealphablending()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagealphablending.php) (or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32243/can-png-image-transparency-be-preserved-when-using-phps-gdlib-imagecopyresample)).

Comment: That does not really answer my question. It's a blind shot as I have no issues with making the background or the image transparent. `imagealphablending` is enabled for true color images by default and `imagecolortransparent` is only useful for palette style images with a single transparent color (eg. GIF).