# Image transparency not preserved when merging two images in PHP

Tags: php, gd

When using examples from other posts to try and merge one PNG that has transparent parts on it with another non-transparent PNG, the foreground PNGs transparency is lost and defaults to white.

The code so far:

```
$width = 349;
$height = 250;

$base_image = imagecreatefrompng($_GET['bg']);
$top_image = imagecreatefrompng($_GET['fg']);
$merged_image = "merged.png";

imagesavealpha($top_image, true);
imagealphablending($top_image, true);

imagecopy($base_image, $top_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);
imagepng($base_image, $merged_image);
```

Can anyone suggest where I may be going wrong?

[image: Coming out like this]
Coming out like this
[image: Should look like this]
Should look like this

Answer (score 0):

Copy from [Can PNG image transparency be preserved when using PHP's GDlib imagecopyresampled?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32302/692076)

Codes should be like this:

```
imagesavealpha($base_image, true);
imagealphablending($base_image, false);
```

Comment: Thanks, didnt seem to solve however. Have found solution at any rate.

Comment: Glad to hear that. maybe you can post your solution as an answer to help others.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $image = imagecreatefrompng($_GET['bg']);
 $frame = imagecreatefrompng($_GET['fg']);

 imagealphablending($frame,true);
 imagecopymerge($image, $frame, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100);

 # Save the image to a file
 imagepng($image, 'file-xyz.png');
```