# PNG - preserving transparency

Tags: php, image-processing, png, gd, alpha

I'm trying to redesign my site so that my original square, tile-based rendering of images can be more of a cutout of the image... to get rid of that grid pattern.

Here's how it looked originally...

[image]

Here's a rough mock-up of what I'm going for:

[image]

So I resaved an image thumbnail with a transparent background... I just want the dog to show, and the square is transparent which will show the site's background underneath.

[image]

Yet when I render it on the page, it has this black background.

[image]

I've checked my CSS to see if there is some sort of img class, or class for the rendered comics... or even the bootstrap to see where there may be a background-color being assigned to black (and also searched for hex code 000000), but didn't find one...

Then I found that it had to do with the way my thumbnailing script was resampling the png... Since I'm getting a black background for the supposedly transparent image, I blame `imagecreatetruecolor()` which `returns an image identifier representing a black image of the specified size.`.

I tried following [Cheekysoft's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32243/can-png-image-transparency-be-preserved-when-using-phps-gdlib-imagecopyresample) here about preserving transparency after resampling... but it didn't work... with his two main points being:

```
imagealphablending( $targetImage, false );
imagesavealpha( $targetImage, true );
```

I found if I put `$img = imagecreatefrompng($image_file);` before I resize/resample it, it displays transparently... which is what I want... but not after I resample it.

**Thumbnailer.php code:**

```
    <?php
#Appreciation goes to digifuzz (http://www.digifuzz.net) for help on this

$image_file = $_GET['img']; //takes in full path of image
$MAX_WIDTH = $_GET['mw'];
$MAX_HEIGHT = $_GET['mh'];
global $img;

//Check for image
if(!$image_file || $image_file == "") { 
    die("NO FILE."); 
}

//If no max width, set one
if(!$MAX_WIDTH || $MAX_WIDTH == "") { 
    $MAX_WIDTH="100"; 
}

//if no max height, set one
if(!$MAX_HEIGHT || $MAX_HEIGHT == "") { 
    $MAX_HEIGHT = "100"; 
}

$img = null;
//create image file from 'img' parameter string
if( preg_match('/\.jpg$/',$image_file) || preg_match('/\.jpeg$/',$image_file) ){ 
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_file); 
} else { 
    $img = imagecreatefrompng($image_file); 
} 

//if image successfully loaded...
if($img) {
    //get image size and scale ratio
    $width = imagesx($img);
    $height = imagesy($img);

    //takes min value of these two
    $scale = min($MAX_WIDTH/$width, $MAX_HEIGHT/$height);

    //if desired new image size is less than original, output new image
    if($scale < 1) {
        $new_width = floor($scale * $width);

        $new_height = floor($scale * $height);


        $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

        //copy and resize old image to new image
        imagecopyresampled($tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

        //replace actual image with new image
        $img = $tmp_img;
    }
}
//set the content type header
header('Content-Type: image/png', true); 

imagealphablending( $img, false );
imagesavealpha( $img, true );
imagepng($img); 


imagedestroy($img);

?>
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call imagealphablending() on your destination image BEFORE you resample/resize the image:

```
//copy and resize old image to new image
imagealphablending($tmp_img, false);
imagecopyresampled($tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
// ...
```

Comment: Oops i was passing in $image_file to imagealphablending(), not $tmp_img... why does it need the temp image and not the original image?

Comment: You have to create image with temp not created image. Your created image will be with black background default

Answer (score 1):

You placed alphablending and traparent code well below after creating image. Just place them before the your createresample line and transparent image with image that created by imagecreatefrompng.

```
imagealphablending( $tmp_img, false );
imagesavealpha( $tmp_img, true );
imagecopyresampled($tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
```

Or you can Try following

```
$img = ImageCreateFromPNG($image_file);
$tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width,$new_height);
imagecolortransparent($tmp_img, imagecolorallocate($tmp_img, 0, 0, 0));
imagecopyresampled($tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
```