# Resize PNGs with php Imagick preserving background

Tags: php, image, imagick

I am trying to resize images using `cropThumbnailImage`. I use `cropThumbnailImage` as it resizes to the shorter length of the original image and crops the image on the longer side equally on both sides so that center portion of the image remains uncropped. This works fine for jpg images but for png images, the resized pngs get a black background.

Following is the code I use.

```
    $image = new \Imagick($src);

    // resize & crop
    $image->cropThumbnailImage($width, $height);

    // save new resized file
    $image->writeImage($dest);
```

Run this code for the following png image.

http://tuxpaint.org/stamps/stamps/animals/birds/cartoon/tux.png
http://www.cs.csubak.edu/~mcabrera/CS211/transparent.png
http://www.tcarms.com/media/assets/productPhotos/006_G2%20Contender/png/Pistol_12in_Ribbed_Blued_2720.png

The output image is resized as required but the png image gets black background.

Tried adding below lines from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32243/can-png-image-transparency-be-preserved-when-using-phps-gdlib-imagecopyresample)but did not work.

```
imagealphablending( $image, false );
imagesavealpha( $image, true );
```

There are other solutions out there in the web which achieve resizing of png images, but I did not find a solution that resizes image the way `cropThumbnailImage` does.

Comment: Aaaand what exactly do you expect? There is no transparency in JPEGs.

Comment: Google harder?  I just did a Google search and came up with a few useful results on my first try.  Check your version number as well.  And as Carsten said, you're using jPEG compression of PNG image.  JPEG does not support transparency.

Comment: JPGs are not transparent... Please refer to PNGs and Gifs files...

Comment: Your code: COMPRESSION_JPEG - JPEG is not PNG, it is without transparency. With this code you convert the PNG into JPEG. You MUST maintan the extension if you want to have transparency...

Comment: Thanks all for pointing out the compression. I removed it and tested. the image still seems to be getting a black background.

Comment: Thanks @BLaZuRE for pointing out the jpeg compression issue. I should probably check the image format before doing this. Any ways I still get the issue.

Comment: @ITChristian I have edited my code. Not compressing with COMPRESSION_JPEG. Can you please point me in right direction for resizing transparent png images.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32337/discussion-between-venkat-kotra-and-itchristian)

Comment: Please check my new edit @VenkatKotra.

Comment: Why is this question closed ? Am willing to add more details to get the question answered.

Comment: @ITChristian Thanks for your time. This code doesnt seem to be working yet.

Comment: Have you defined variables?

Comment: Please tell me your error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is not transparency in your JPG... The JPG is not a transparent image... PNG and GIF are necessary here.
2. If you are refering to PNG, there is a PHP code who will help you to resize PNGs with transparency:

> $x = "COORDINATES - X for crop";
>
> $y = "COORDINATES - y for crop";
>
> $w = "width";
>
> $h = "height";
>
> $img = imagecreatefrompng($img_path);
>
> imagealphablending($img, true);
>
> $img_cropped = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
>
> imagesavealpha($img_cropped, true);
>
> imagealphablending($img_cropped, false);
>
> $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($img_cropped, 0, 0, 0, 127);
>
> imagefill($img_cropped, 0, 0, $transparent);
>
> imagecopyresampled($img_cropped, $img, 0, 0, $x, $y, $w, $h, $w, $h); // you can also use imagecopy() here
>
> imagepng($img_cropped, "your_image_cropped.png", 2);
>
> imagedestroy($img);
>
> imagedestroy($img_cropped);

EDIT: Try this:

> $image = imagecreatefrompng ( $filename );
>
> $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor ( $width, $height ); // new wigth and height
>
> imagealphablending($new_image , false);
>
> imagesavealpha($new_image , true);
>
> imagecopyresampled ( $new_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, imagesx ( $image ), imagesy ( $image ) );
>
> $image = $new_image;
>
> // saving
>
> imagealphablending($image , false);
>
> imagesavealpha($image , true);
>
> imagepng ( $image, $filename );

***Don't forget to define $filename, $width, $height!!!!***

Comment: The question asks how to resize png's using Imagick, not GD library.

Comment: this will cause a grey border when resizing images with semi transparent pixels

Answer (score 2):

Transparency is preserved using the following snippet:

```
$im = new Imagick($imgPath);
$im->setImageFormat('png');
$im->writeImage('/files/thumbnails/new_title.png');
```