# image manipulation width and height setting

Tags: php, image-processing, image-manipulation

in my project i just do image watermarking or image combine it's working fine and code for that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// Give the Complete Path of the folder where you want to save the image    
$folder="uploads/";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], "$folder".$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$file='uploads/'.$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];

$uploadimage=$folder.$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
$newname= time();

$ext = pathinfo($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Set the thumbnail name
$thumbnail = $folder.$newname.".".$ext; 
$imgname=$newname.".".$ext;

// Load the mian image
if ($ext=="png" || $ext=="PNG") {
$source = imagecreatefrompng($uploadimage);
}
else if ($ext=="gif" || $ext=="GIF") {
$source = imagecreatefromgif($uploadimage);
}
else if ($ext=="bmp" || $ext=="BMP") {
$source = imagecreatefrombmp($uploadimage);
}
else{
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadimage);
}

// load the image you want to you want to be watermarked
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng('uploads/logo1.png');

// get the width and height of the watermark image
$water_width = imagesx($source)/2;
$water_height = imagesy($watermark);

// get the width and height of the main image image
$main_width = imagesx($source);
$main_height = imagesy($source);

$im_middle_w = $main_width/2;
$im_middle_h = $main_height/2;

// Set the dimension of the area you want to place your watermark we use 0
// from x-axis and 0 from y-axis 
$dime_x = $im_middle_w - $water_width/2;
$dime_y = $im_middle_h - $water_height/2;

// copy both the images
imagecopy($source, $watermark, $dime_x, $dime_y, 0, 0, $water_width, $water_height);

// Final processing Creating The Image
imagejpeg($source, $thumbnail, 100);
unlink($file);
}
?>
<img src='uploads/<?php echo $imgname;?>'>
</body>
</html>
```

but problem with setting **$water_width** and i want set as half of my source image. but when i have source image of less width or more width compare to $water_width it's set it like that. see image when source image width is more.

[image]
and when width is less.
[image]
so my problem is how to set **$water_width** as half of source image width?

by Alex your answer it's came up like this.
[image]

Comment: What do you need as water mark?. **Www.domain.com** ?? @divyesh

Comment: yes.any sentence without black background like last image in question.

Comment: I think you can use `imagettftext`. Check my answer. @Divyesh

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will resize watermark to half-width of original image and put it in the centre:

```
// load the image you want to you want to be watermarked
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng('uploads/logo1.png');

// get the width and height of the watermark image
$water_width = imagesx($watermark);
$water_height = imagesy($watermark);

// get the width and height of the main image image
$main_width = imagesx($source);
$main_height = imagesy($source);

// resize watermark to half-width of the image
$new_height = round($water_height * $main_width / $water_width / 2);
$new_width = round($main_width / 2);
$new_watermark = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
// keep transparent background
imagealphablending( $new_watermark, false );
imagesavealpha( $new_watermark, true );

imagecopyresampled($new_watermark, $watermark, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $water_width, $water_height);

// Set the dimension of the area you want to place your watermark we use 0
// from x-axis and 0 from y-axis 
$dime_x = round(($main_width - $new_width)/2);
$dime_y = round(($main_height - $new_height)/2);

// copy both the images
imagecopy($source, $new_watermark, $dime_x, $dime_y, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height);

// Final processing Creating The Image
imagejpeg($source, $thumbnail, 100);

imagedestroy($source);
imagedestroy($watermark);
imagedestroy($new_watermark);
```

Comment: i show image using your answer it's display black background...how to do it as other image in question?

Comment: @DivyeshJesadiya, I have amended the answer to preserve alpha channel in the watermark. As a side note, the transparency question's been answered multiple times. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32243/can-png-image-transparency-be-preserved-when-using-phps-gdlib-imagecopyresample.

Answer (score 3):

You can try `imagettftext` method, if you don't want any such high perfection in transparency. You can have try of this code. You have to save a font file in your directory, here I used arial.ttf.

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng("png.png");  //create image data
$font = 'arial.ttf';  //font file name
$randomString  = "example.com";   //string need to be shown
$main_width = imagesx($im);       //finding width and height
$main_height = imagesy($im);      
$posx= $main_width/2;    //finding center 
$posy = $main_height/2;
$color = imagecolorallocate($im, 200, 200, 200);  //Creating color 
$size = ($main_width/25)+1;     //determine size of font. +1 to avoid 0
$temp = $size*5;     
$posx = $posx-$temp;    //adjust to average center
imagettftext($im,$size,0, $posx, $posy, $color, $font , $randomString);   //apply a text
```

You have to adjust `posx` and `posy` for your text position. `Size` also can be adjusted with some logics.

`$color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);`= black

and `$color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);`  = white.

You have to adjust this for your required text color.