# Transparency not preserved after applying imagecopyresampled

Tags: php, image, png, gd

I have a question related to the GD library on PHP. I can't add a transparent image to the canvas in a way that preserves the transparency.

Here is the output that I get
[image]

Here is the code that I used

```
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor(4000, 4000);
imagealphablending($canvas, false);
imagesavealpha($canvas, true);
$color = imagecolorallocatealpha($canvas, 255, 250, 156, 0);
imagefill($canvas, 0, 0, $color);

$mask = imagecreatefrompng('mask.png');
imagealphablending($mask, false);
imagesavealpha($mask, true);

imagecopyresampled($canvas, $mask, 500, 500, 0, 0, 1500, 1500, imagesx($mask), imagesy($mask));

header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($canvas);
exit;
```

As you can see, the image with the dog has a white background, but I need a yellow background (like on the canvas) instead of this white background.

Please write what is my mistake. Thank you very much.

Comment: You'd need to provide the input images separately if you wanted some assistance.

Comment: Need to call `imagealphablending` and `imagesavealpha` on the target `$canvas`. [See this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32302/21146235) for an example.

Comment: @motto hi. But I did it at the very beginning of the script.

Answer (score 0):

I found problems, I shouldn't have used this code

```
imagealphablending($canvas, false);
imagesavealpha($canvas, true);
```

Thx